# Проблема с интеграцией VK API в Spring

Tags: java, spring, vkontakte-api

Я работаю по документации https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK.
Пытаюсь использовать VK API в своём Spring приложении.

Вот **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
      compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.11.2'
      compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.2'
      compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.2'
      compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version: '1.7.26'
      implementation 'com.vk.api:sdk:1.0.8'
      implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
      implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-explorer'
      developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
      testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'}
```

Вот **src\main\resources\log4j2.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Configuration status="info">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Вот **src\main\resources\logging.properties**:

```
.level=INFO
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
deng.level=FINEST
```

Из всех инструкций не удалось совершить только:

> Установить системную переменную, указывающую путь до файла:
> `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Student/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.11.2/4d44e4edc4a7fb39f09b95b09f560a15976fa1ba/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Student/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.7.26/c82cee90e4308cf6789d3d20255e30a670261fe7/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.26.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Student/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.begin(Sink.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.begin(Sink.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.begin(Sink.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:501)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.lambda$getCallerClass$3(StackLocator.java:49)
    at java.base/java.lang.StackStreamFactory$StackFrameTraverser.consumeFrames(StackStreamFactory.java:534)
    at java.base/java.lang.StackStreamFactory$AbstractStackWalker.doStackWalk(StackStreamFactory.java:306)
    at java.base/java.lang.StackStreamFactory$AbstractStackWalker.callStackWalk(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.StackStreamFactory$AbstractStackWalker.beginStackWalk(StackStreamFactory.java:370)
    at java.base/java.lang.StackStreamFactory$AbstractStackWalker.walk(StackStreamFactory.java:243)
    at java.base/java.lang.StackWalker.walk(StackWalker.java:498)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.getCallerClass(StackLocator.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.getCallerClass(StackLocatorUtil.java:55)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:39)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
```

**Как такое исправить?**

Comment: у вас искючение StackOverflowError, что говорит о переполнении памяти (стека). причем тут вообще ВК? вы до него еще не дошли. ищите утечку памяти

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, попробуй так

```
dependencies {
      implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
      implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-explorer'
      developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
      testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
      compile ('com.vk.api:sdk:1.0.7') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j'
      }
}
```

И тогда файлы `src\main\resources\log4j2.xml` и `src\main\resources\logging.properties` не понадобятся